# Use $axios in a module in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to be able the same `axios` instance used in the auth module (https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) in a javascript module where I make my API calls

I have the following

```
const BASE_URL = 'job';

export default {
  getJobs(params?: Filter) {
    return axios.get(BASE_URL, { params });
  },
  getJob(slug: string, params?: Filter) {
    return axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${slug}`, { params });
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to use the same $axios instance inside of this js module. Something like:

```
const BASE_URL = 'job';

export default {
  getJobs(params?: Filter) {
    return this.$axios.get(BASE_URL, { params });
  },
  getJob(slug: string, params?: Filter) {
    return this.$axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${slug}`, { params });
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to get axios instance using `this.$axios` in Nuxt.js

[image]

Comment: When I use `this.$axios` I get `undefined`. It is worth to remember that this code is in a separate `.js` file which acts as an API service

Comment: I am using nuxt typescript and it is already defined there, when creating nuxt project you have to select axios on setup to include it